# Will DirectSound run on Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, directx-9, directsound

I'm referring to DirectSound, a component of DirectX 9.0c.

I know the MediaElement is the preferred audio class but it does not provide some of the DirectSound audio function that my app needs, specifically ability to specify audio output device destination. MediaElement will only play to the current default audio playback device -- unless it is getting an upgrade with Win8.

Answer (score 1):

[DirectX is encouraged in metro apps and desktop applications.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/04/02/xaudio2-and-windows-8-consumer-preview.aspx)  DirectSound is not used because [XAudio2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh441485.aspx#intro), it's successor, is what is recommended.

> XAudio2 is a low-level audio library for Windows that specifically
>   supports game audio. It provides a digital signal processing (DSP) and
>   audio-graph engine for games. **XAudio2 expands on its predecessors,
>   DirectSound and XAudio**, by supporting computing trends such as SIMD
>   floating-point architectures and HD audio. It also supports the more
>   complex sound processing demands of today’s games.

Comment: Thanks mydogisbox for the reply. I looked at XAudio2 when it was introduced. My app allows the user to pick audio files on his/her harddrive and play it -- kind of like a Windows Media Player but it does additional stuff. XAudio2 requires that the audio file be preprocessed for XAudio2 before it can be played. So it is not suited to my app.

Comment: What file types do you want to support?

Comment: I know DirectSound only supports WAV. So that is the only format file that I can specify output destination for. 

But my app also allows the user select the WMP audio driver for almost any audio format file ( WAV, MP3, WMA, MIDI (MID), AU, AIFF (AIF), MPEG (MPG), and WMV ). And more if you install a Codec.